# Composing functions

Tags: functions, notation

Is there any common notation for a composed version of functions $F:X\to Y$, $G:X\to Z$ given as $H(x)=(F(x),G(x))$ and of functions $F:X\to Z$, $G:Y\to W$, given as $H(x,y)=(F(x),G(y))$?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your mathematical expressions.

Comment: Hi! I fixed your formulae and you migth want to take a look if I didn't messed something up. What exactly do you want to compose? It's not completely clear and it would be quite helpful if you could add more details with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3512784/edit) explaining what exactly you're looking for and maybe also why :)

Answer (score 0):

I would write $( f, g )$ for $x \mapsto (f(x), g(x))$ and $f \times g$ for $(x, y) \mapsto (f(x), g(x))$. The notation $(f, g)$ reflects the fact that $x \mapsto (f(x), g(x))$ provides the witnesses showing that the [bifunctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Bifunctors_and_multifunctors) $(\times):(X, Y) \mapsto X \times Y$ is the [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) in the category of sets of the sets $X$ and $Y$. The notation $f \times g$ reflects the fact that $(x, y) \mapsto (f(x), g(x))$ gives  the morphisms part of that bifunctor.

Comment: well. the idea  with $(f,g)$ is quite clear, by I do not like using the $\times$ here since functions are also sets and one could need to take a cartesian product of two functions for some reason. I thought rather about using $\otimes$ (tensor product), but I was not sure if it agrees with the common use.

Comment: Your objection to $f \times g$ applies *mutatis mutandis* to $(f, g)$. Using $f \otimes g$ for $f \times g$ would seem to me  quite odd. You are going to have to explain your notational conventions to your reader anyway, so why not say that you are using $(f, g)$ and $f \times g$ in the category theory sense (except where otherwise stated, if you ever need pairs of products of functions viewed as sets).

Comment: You are clearly right. Thanks !